# Solving a constrained inhomogeneous first order ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and $b \in \mathbf{R}^n$. I want to solve the following ODE, 
$$
\dot{x} + 2Ax +2b = 0,
$$
with $x: \mathbf{R}_+ \to \mathbf{S}^{n-1}$, so the domain is the nonnegative reals and codomain is the the unit sphere. Is this possible with the implicit constraints on $x$? Are there good references that explain how to solve this type of ODE numerically and analyze it mathematically (i.e., stable equilibrium, etc.)?

Comment: You cannot *solve* the ODE with such constraints.  However, you can write the DE satisfied by the directions of the solutions to the original DE.  If my calculations are correct, that should be: $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{x(t)}{\lVert x(t) \rVert} = -2 \left( (\langle x(t), A x(t) \rangle + \langle x(t), b \rangle ) \frac{x(t)}{\lVert x(t) \rVert^2} - A x(t) - b \right).$$

Comment: And if $b = 0$ the equilibria of the "new" DE are just eigenvectors of the matrix $A$.  Certainly there are references, and, hopefully, some expert on control theory will read your post and give them.  I can (and do) upvote your post only.

Comment: @user539887, yes I hope so, I am very interested in solution methods and how to understand equilibria.